# Linq List<string> union

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use Linq to find common items between 2 generic lists of type string.

For example, say I have the following code, I would like to get a List < string> which would contain item2 and item3:

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
List<string> List2 = new List<string>();

List1.Add("item1");
List1.Add("item2");
List1.Add("item3");

List2.Add("item2");
List2.Add("item3");
List2.Add("item4");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var items = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

See also:

- [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)
- Much recommended: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 5):

I know LINQ was tagged, but just for completeness; if LINQ isn't an option;

```
List<string> result = list1.FindAll(list2.Contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var List3 = list1.Intersect(list2)
```

Comment: It seems large portions of your answer intersect with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from item in list1
where list2.Contains(item)
select item
```

will work for valuetypes.